# Creating a single sided vault, using float for calculating ratio

Tags: security, math

When making a single sided vault, aka deposit X get Y. is it safe to just use a float to get the ratio?

right now I just calculate the ratio with like so:

```
(x_underlying_token_account_amount as f64) / (y_lp_mint_supply as f64)
```

Meaning you get more x per y as underlying increases compared to the lp_mint supply.

I let people deposit and withdraw based on that ratio. Ive played around with more precise libraries to get precise number etc, but they all give me the same number as the method above.

I feel like its safe to assume that with single sided vaults this is a safe approach to getting the ratio for deposits and withdrawals but I would love to get some input from a pro

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid floats if you're doing financial math, especially if you're just dividing one amount by another. On the flip-side, it's much easier to implement using floats.

As long as you properly take the floor or ceiling of the output number, you'll probably be OK, but I wouldn't recommend it for a production application, since it's always possible for a surprise result. If it's possible to get a surprise, someone will very likely exploit it.

I would suggest writing some fuzzing tests. If those all pass, then maybe it is safe for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up using this solution, gives me the same result as the float calculation every time but i suppose its safer!

// Calculate the amount of underlying tokens to withdraw
  let pool_liquidity = ctx.accounts.pool_underlying_token_account.amount;
  let lp_supply = ctx.accounts.lp_mint.supply;
  let amount_to_withdraw: u64 = (lp_tokens_redeemed as u128)
    .checked_mul(pool_liquidity as u128)
    .unwrap()
    .checked_div(lp_supply as u128)
    .unwrap()
    .try_into()
    .unwrap();

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to round down for withdrawal calculations. That way, the user never gets too much.